# Javascript file inclusion 406 error in CakePHP

Tags: javascript, jquery, cakephp, include

I have several js files under webroot

http://www.in-culture.info/app/webroot/js/

All the files are ok

Eg http://www.in-culture.info/app/webroot/js/lightbox.js

Except this

http://www.in-culture.info/app/webroot/js/jquery.cookie.js

It's throwing 406 Not acceptable error.

Help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check file permissions, also try changing filename.

Comment: You shouldn't need to change the name. My system works fine with that jQuery naming convention. What is your hosting setup?

Comment: justhost.com cpanel
The domain is an add-on domain

Answer (score 0):

If your server has `mod_security` enabled (which is usually present on cPanel hostings) the problem is that `mod_security` blocks filenames containing the text ".cookie".

So the solution is to rename the file to somethign else.

[Source](http://www.fixkb.com/2014/08/jquery-cookie-js-error-406-not-acceptable.html)